# Getting list of files and folders in public Dropbox folder and downloading files

Tags: api, python-3.x, web-scraping, dropbox

Asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107030/can-i-prevent-an-app-from-modifying-files-in-my-dropbox), I was trying to find a way to give a read-only access for my application to my Dropbox. It seems that it is not really possible, since there is no way to give it read-only permissions.

So I've decided that making a certain folder public and providing a link to it would be sufficient. The question is: is there a convenient way in Python to get a list of files and subfolders in a public Dropbox folder, and download files? Something more convenient than just going ahead and brutally scraping the page using, say, `dryscrape` (because it can be horribly slow, and also tedious to program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see [`/metadata/link`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata-link) in the v1 API. Note that you still need a Dropbox app, but you don't need to link it to an account (so it doesn't gain access to anything except whatever shared link you provide it).